# Issue using bind variable in dynamic SOQL and How to Incoporate two input value sets to Apex:map

Tags: apex, visualforce, map

I have requirement like,Find the Person Accounts within X miles from  the current Location. My code as follows: I am getting error on Where part. I am not sure how to include the miles variable. Pls advise.

```
public PageReference findNearby() {

    String lat, lon;
    String miles;
    // Format: "<latitude>,<longitude>" (must have comma, but only one comma)
    List <String> latlon = currentPosition.split(',');
    lat = latlon[0].trim();
    lon = latlon[1].trim();
    // SOQL query to get the nearest Contacts
    String queryString =
        'SELECT Id, Name, MailingStreet, MailingCity, MailingPostalCode , MailingState, Donation_Request__c, Phone, Location__longitude__s, Location__latitude__s ' +
        'FROM Contact where Location__longitude__s != null and Location__latitude__s != null ' +
        'WHERE DISTANCE(Location__c, GEOLOCATION(' + lat + ',' + lon + '), \'mi\') < :miles ' +
        'ORDER BY DISTANCE(Location__c, GEOLOCATION(' + lat + ',' + lon + '), \'mi\') ' +
        'LIMIT 10';
    System.Debug('>>>> the value of queryString is ' + queryString);
    contacts = database.query(queryString);
    if (contacts.size() <= 0) {
        System.debug('No results. Query: ' + queryString);
    }
    return null;
}
```

VF Markup

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Map" id="map">
    <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!resultsAvailable}" title="Locations">
        <apex:map width="590px" height="300px" center="38.9047,77.0164">
            <!-- Add markers for contacts -->
            <apex:repeat value="{!lstAccount}" var="con">
                <apex:mapMarker title="{!con.Name}" position="{latitude:{!con.Location__Latitude__s},longitude:{!con.Location__Longitud‌​e__s}}">
                    <apex:mapInfoWindow>
```

Another Issue is , I have already mapped some Values(coming from a Search criteria) to `apex:map`. Along with that , How can i incorporate the result from the above case(X miles from the current location). I couldn't paste code reg with the issue here. It pasted in the below part.

Comment: I could nt paste the follwoing code to my above question. So pasted here. Pls look over here.               <apex:pageBlock title="Map" id="map">
 <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!resultsAvailable}" title="Locations">
 <apex:map width="590px" height="300px" center="38.9047,77.0164" >
 <!-- Add markers for contacts -->
 <apex:repeat value="{!lstAccount}" var="con">
 <apex:mapMarker title="{!con.Name}"
 position="{latitude:{!con.Location__Latitude__s},longitude:{!con.Location__Longitude__s}}">
 <apex:mapInfoWindow >

Comment: Replace `< :miles ' +` by `< '+miles+`

Comment: @abdn - That is not necessary, you can use bind variables in dynamic SOQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `miles` property is a string and the DISTANCE returns a ?decimal so you will simply need to change the field type:

```
Decimal miles;
```

Also, you are not setting the value for miles in your code so you will need to assign it a value, per your requirements, as well

As for your second question, once you get the query part done, please ask as a new question as it is unclear what your are asking and without code there is no context.

Comment: Thanks Eric . It worked. :).             And for the Second Issue, like you said ,I raised a new Question. Pls check that.